# Hide/Show Nav on Vertical Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I've implemented a scroll based state change on my nav bar, which fades in a fixed position nav at the screen top after the user scrolls down a lengthy page and then hides it and puts it back in it's relative position again as they scroll back up to see the top of the page. It works great 90% of the time.  Here's my code..

```
function scrollNavReveal() {
var nav = $('nav.nav-primary');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollpos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollpos > 200) && (scrollpos < 800)) {
      nav.fadeOut(500);
    }
    else if (scrollpos > 800) {
          nav.css({"position": "fixed", "width": "100%"}).fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
      nav.css({"position": "relative", "width": "100%", "display": "block"});
    }
});
```

}

The issue is that when I scroll to the page top very quickly with my mouse, sometimes the nav does not appear.  I have to make a small scroll on the mouse and then it pops back into place.  This also happens when I use my scroll to top function which is initiated when a user clicks the 'go to top' button in the footer.

```
function go_to_top() {
    $('a.naada-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
})
```

}

In the go_to_top function I believe the `.animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');` does not take into account the height of the nav itself, which isn't currently in `position: relative;` (hence not in the normal DOM flow/scroll height).

Both issues seem very similar, but slightly different and they can be seen and tested here [naada.staging.wpengine.com](http://naada.staging.wpengine.com)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Given url is not working.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that.

Comment: Why don't you use a class instead of applying css proprieties with jQuery? Look at this Fiddle (taken from another question here on stack) http://jsfiddle.net/gxRC9/501/

Comment: Well I figure out how to work with the go_to_top() function so that my menu is revealed when it's clicked.  The trick was to use jQuery's .animate() complete argument, which is a function added to the end of the animate method.   function go_to_top() {
  $('a.naada-top').click(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:10}, 'slow', function(){
          $('nav.nav-primary').fadeIn(100);
        });
    })
   }

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding an if statement for < 200 rather than an else at the end of the statement. If you don't have to roll through each if statement and prove them false the processing speed will be quicker, which might catch the quicker scroll a little better. I also use the (document).scroll(function(){ instead of window... but it should work either way.

Here's how I would code this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
   var scroll_dst = ($(document).scrollTop());                          
   if (scroll_dst < 200){   
       nav.css({"position": "relative", "width": "100%", "display": "block"});
   }else if((scroll_dst >= 200) && (scroll_dst < 800)) {
       nav.fadeOut(500);
   }else if((scroll_dst >= 800){
       nav.css({"position": "fixed", "width": "100%"}).fadeIn(500);
   }
});
```

You could also make it so when you click the 'go to top' function it automatically places the nav.css back to it's relative state. It's not a perfect solution, but it's better than having no nav at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had thought to try to re-order my if statement as well, but that didn't have any beneficial effect.  Actually it was worse performance, only staying visible if I returned tot he page top at a very slow scroll. (Not sure why!).   Also setting my nav back to it's relative state on the 'go to top' doesn't work as my scrollNavReveal() function overrides it and keeps it 'display: none;'.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently functions attached to scroll events can be very resource heavy and I think the biggest issue with my code is that the browser couldn't evaluate each of my if statements for every pixel that was scrolled, especially when you scrolled fast to the page top. So I've found a more elegant [solution](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c#.zestp0d10).

In this solution the scroll information is stored in a boolean and he uses a setInterval to check on the scroll position.  It's not exactly the same interactivity that I had before, but based on the circumstances it seems the most elegant and resource friendly option. It's actually really pretty code..

You can see it live [here.](http://naada.staging.wpengine.com)